# Multiple inheritance: I keep geting compile errors

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I have a Base class which inherits a class with an empty constructor and i then have another class which inherits a class with an empty constructor but i also want this class to inherit my base class but i keep geting errors my code is below

**BmvMessage - Base class
BmvMessage inherits - DboGenBmvMessage
BmvMessageStructure inherits - DboGenBmvMessageStruture
I also want BmvMessageStructure to inherit BmvMessage**

```
HPP
    class BmvMessage : public DboGenBmvMessage
        {
    // code
    };

HPP OF CLASS THAT I WANT TO INHERIT WITH
class BmvMessageStructure : public DboGenBmvMessageStructure , public BmvMessage
{
//CODE
};

CPP OF THIS CLASS 
    BmvMessageStructure::BmvMessageStructure() : DboGenBmvMessageStructure(), BmvMessage()
    {
    }
```

Comment: What errors is your compiler giving?

Comment: expected class-name before `{` token @Moo-Juice

Comment: Are you `#include`ing all the necessary hpp files?

Comment: The only problems with that code are the missing `;` after the class definitions and the missing definitions of `DboGenBmvMessage` and `DboGenBmvMessageStructure`. What errors do you get?

Comment: @MikeSeymour i do not need the `;` after class definitions because they are not in the same file i just put them there like that and the error is **"Epected class-name before { token"**

Comment: @MikeSeymour you mean the `#inlude` for `BmvMessage` when you say missing definitions right?

Answer (score 0):

Without error information it is hard to figure out the issue. First thing that springs to mind is, do you have a terminating `;` on your class definition?

```
class BmvMessage : public DboGenBmvMessage
    {
// code
}; // <-
```

Otherwise perhaps it is an order of declaration issue - are you `#include`*-ing* your base classes in the correct order and are they correctly defined?

Comment: ah i think its because i forgot to include `BmvMessage` in `BmvMessageStrucute`

Answer (score 0):

You are sure you have all the required headers included before inheriting? Line in which error occurs would be nice.

Comment: error is **"Epected class-name before { token"** @PawelZubrycki but i think it is because i did not `#include` `BmvMessage`